# Accessing multiple sensors in non-activity classes

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I am trying to use multiple sensors like Accelerator,Magnetic Field, Light and so on and for each sensor I wrote an individual class which not an activity , each of them has its SensorEventListener as well. What I want to do is when user chooses one of them I start to show the data on a fragment(on MainActivity) , when user changes the previous sensor should stop and new one should start. However,  when I try to stop previous one by unregistering its listener , it doesn't unregister but it registers and works. I want to stop previous listener. What is wrong? Any ideas?

Here is the sensor class;

```
public class Accelerometer
{
    private  SensorManager sensorManager;
    private   Sensor sensor;
    public List<ObjAccelerometer> lstData;
    ObjAccelerometer currentData;
    float lastX,lastY,lastZ;
    String currentTime;
    int  numberOfSamples;
    Context context;

  public  Accelerometer(Context _context,int _numberSample)
    {
        context=_context;
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        numberOfSamples=_numberSample;
        lstData=new ArrayList<>();

    }
    public void registerUnregister(boolean register)

    {
        if(register)
            sensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        else
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
    }


    Calendar time;




    private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if(numberOfSamples>lstData.size()) {
                if (currentData != null) {
                    lastX = currentData.get_x();
                    lastY = currentData.get_y();
                    lastZ = currentData.get_z();
                }
                currentData = new ObjAccelerometer();
                time = Calendar.getInstance();
                currentTime = time.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + time.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + time.get(Calendar.SECOND) + ":" + time.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                currentData.set_time(currentTime);
                currentData.set_x(event.values[0]);
                currentData.set_y(event.values[1]);
                currentData.set_z(event.values[2]);
                Float speed = Math.abs(event.values[0] + event.values[1] + event.values[2] - lastX - lastY - lastZ);
                currentData.set_speed(speed);
                lstData.add(currentData);
                Util.createToaster(context, "X Y Z Time:" + currentData.toString());

            }
            else
                registerUnregister(false);
        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }

    };
}
```

Here the code for calling them ;

```
   unRegisterAllSensors();
  switch (selectedSensor) {

                case Accelerometer:
                    accelerometer= new Accelerometer(context, DEFAULT_SAMPLE_NUMBER);
                     accelerometer.registerUnregister(true);
                    lstAccelerometer = accelerometer.lstData;
                    break;
                case Linear_Accelerometer:
                     linearAccelerometer= new LinearAccelerometer(context, DEFAULT_SAMPLE_NUMBER);
                    linearAccelerometer.registerUnregister(true);

                    break;
....
```

Here is the unRegisterAllSensors() function code:

```
 if(accelerometer!=null) {
            accelerometer.registerUnregister(false);
            accelerometer=null;
        }
        if(linearAccelerometer!=null) {
            linearAccelerometer.registerUnregister(false);
            linearAccelerometer=null;
        }
```

Comment: Based on the code in your question this should work. Maybe post some more code that takes part in the whole process. Are you sure that the code responsible for sensors switching is called?

Comment: there is no other code , I am just selecting the sensor and  based on selection creating an instance of the class and showing the data as a toast message on the screen. The sensor switching is working fine too. The problem is unregistering the sensoreventlistener

Comment: Maybe add a log message after `sensorManager.registerListener` and `sensorManager.unregisterListener` to see if they are called when they're supposed to.

Comment: I added  it seems it is not the problem

Comment: That means that the last call of `registerUnregister` for particular sensor that is causing the problem follows a path calling `sensorManager.unregisterListener` and you're still getting data for this listener?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about bothering people,it actually works!
I made  a few changes including setting SensorManager final parameter and also removing Toast message and add A toaster only for register and unregister of each listener. It worked! I believe the problem was caused by two things;
1-Toasting the message is slower process than sensing because of that even though I unregistered messages were still on the screen for a while.
2- when I didn't define SensorManager final , every time I was getting a new instance of it so size of the listener list was 0.

Still, this can be a good sample for people who want to call sensors from non-activity classes.
Thanks!

Comment: Toast are not the best way to debug an application. Use logs for that.